# ~~ MS SQL Update all records that contain a string and replace string with new string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Here's an example table:

[image]

I'm trying to write a SQL Statement (MS SQL) that will look for records containing a specific string and then replace that string with a new string.

In this example we let's say we want to see all records that:

1. Contain the string:  "~/main/fruits/apples"
2. Replace the "contains string" with string: "~/main/fruits/stuff"

The system should edit record IDs: 4, 7, and 8 in this fashion:
[image]

My failed attempt is this:

```
UPDATE mydb.dbo.test 
SET [FILE_PATH] = 
(
    SELECT REPLACE('~/main/fruits/apples', 'apples', 'stuff') WHERE ([FILE_PATH] LIKE '~/main/fruits/apples%')
)
WHERE ([FILE_PATH] LIKE '~/main/fruits/apples%');
```

The problem with the statement above is that for IDs 7 and 8 it revises them to both equal: '~/main/fruits/stuff'

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
UPDATE mydb.dbo.test 
    SET FILE_PATH = REPLACE(FILE_PATH, 'apples', 'stuff') 
    WHERE FILE_PATH LIKE '~/main/fruits/apples%';
```

Personally, though, I would align the replace pattern with the `like` pattern, so it was more like:

```
UPDATE mydb.dbo.test 
    SET FILE_PATH = REPLACE(FILE_PATH, '~/main/fruits/apples', '~/main/fruits/stuff') 
    WHERE FILE_PATH LIKE '~/main/fruits/apples%';
```

This prevents a problem if `apples` occurs more than once in the path.

Comment: This is perfect. And I agree, the second option is better to prevent multiple occurrences. Thank you! I will select this when the timer allows me